# Why can't this code run in CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Query code:

```
$query = $this->db->query(
    'SELECT course.*, AVG(course_review.`rating`) AS `avg_rating`
     FROM course
     LEFT JOIN course_review ON `course`.`id` = `course_review`.`course_id`
     WHERE `course`.`course_category`= ' . $id . '
       AND `course`.`approved`= 3
       AND `course`.`delete_course` != 1
       AND `course`.`unpublish_course` != 1
     GROUP BY `course`.`id`
     ORDER BY avg_rating DESC');

return $query->result()
```

Thanks

Comment: check the query executed by using `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: thanks bro, i can't get it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this code isn't running, so the avg_rating is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query for your problem :

**Query:-**

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT
  course.id,
  AVG(course_review.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM course
LEFT JOIN course_review
  ON course.id = course_review.course_id
WHERE course.course_category = ' . $id . '
AND course.approved = 3
AND course.delete_course != 1
AND course.unpublish_course != 1
GROUP BY course.id
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC');

return $query->result();
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this query"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Please post your table structure and sample data for query performing..